# Sequelize association where one of the models varies

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Let's say I have three models: `Bucket` `Water` and `Sand`. A `Bucket` can have an association with `Water` or `Sand` but not both. So in theory, my relationship definitions would look like this:

```
Bucket.hasOne(Water, { as: 'contents' })
Water.belongsTo(Bucket)

Bucket.hasOne(Sand, { as: 'contents' })
Sand.belongsTo(Bucket)
```

This should create a foreign key column on the Water and Sand tables referencing a bucket. And then, in theory, if I query Bucket.getContents() I'll get either the water or the sand object.

Is this legit? I couldn't find any examples of an association like this in the docs. Is there a better way to do it?

Although this is a contrived example, the reason for `Water` and `Sand` being different models is they each have a lot of columns that are unique to their model, so it makes sense to keep them separate than try to make one combined model.

Comment: Have you checked polymorphic associations in sequelize? Is this close to what you want? https://sequelize.org/master/manual/polymorphic-associations.html

Comment: Hey @Emma, I had not found that thank you, looks exactly like what I need. However the setup is so complex, not sure if it's really worth it vs. just adding two foreign keys or some other solution entirely.